# python iterator from list of iterators into queue of data chunks from inner iterators

Tags: python, pandas, iterator, queue, generator

I have directory with csv files -> `'data'`
I load each csv into dataframe as iterator with chunksize parameter -> inner_it
It results in list of iterators -> ll
I want to load all chunks from each inner_it into queue.
How to do it in a clean way?

Currently I do:

```
import os

import pandas as pd


def sample_gen(df):
    yield next(df)


def get_next(df, qq):
    try:
        while True:
            z = next(df)
            print(z.shape)
    except StopIteration:
        pass
    finally:
        qq.append(z)
        return qq


ll = iter([pd.read_csv(os.path.join(f'data/{x}'), chunksize=10**6) for x in os.listdir('data')])
qq = []


def load_queue(ll, qq):
    try:
        inner_it = next(ll)
        qq = get_next(inner_it, qq)
    except StopIteration:
        load_queue(ll, qq)
    finally:
        return qq, ll
```

I do not know how to work out load_queue

**EDIT:**
I have decided to flatten my list of iterators and use generators instead. Here is my final solution below:

```
import os
import threading
import concurrent.futures
import queue
import time
import pandas as pd


def producer(queue, event):
    ll = (pd.read_csv(os.path.join(f'data/{x}'), chunksize=10 ** 6) for x in os.listdir('data'))
    ll = (chunk for each_iterator in ll for chunk in each_iterator)

    while True:
        try:
            message = next(ll)
            queue.put(message, "P")
        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)
            event.set()
            break
    print('producer got exit event')


def consumer(queue, event):
    while not event.is_set():
        message = queue.get()
        print(message.shape, 'C')
    print('consumer got exit event')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pipeline = queue.Queue(maxsize=10)
    event = threading.Event()

    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
        executor.submit(producer, pipeline, event)
        executor.submit(consumer, pipeline, event)
```

Comment: Ok, I have flattened the iterators.

Comment: You can use also ```chain.from_iterable``` (itertools module) to flatten your iterators